# ERC721 Royalties - how to determine what token sale the royalty payment came from

Tags: solidity, erc-721, opensea

Whenever a royalty amount is paid out for the sale of an NFT is it possible to determine which token was sold to cause the royalty payment?

I have a smart contract as the recipient address of royalties via EIP-2981 -- whenever the smart contract receives a payment for royalties I want to be able to determine what token(s) caused that royalty payment.

Based on how OpenSea pays out royalties, in a "bulk transaction" every 1-2 weeks, it sounds like royalties from multiple token sales will be in that one payment, so I'm not sure how I'd be able to determine the tokens that were sold and the amount of royalty for each token.